# Laravel : To use $_GET or $_POST for search

Tags: php, forms, query-string, laravel

In all laravel tutorials, they use the POST method for forms. For searching, I thought it was better to have the FORM use GET instead, so that as soon as the the form gets submitted, the query string is appended to the URL, and the controller can directly work on that.

If its a POST method, then the form is submitted to an intermediate controller, which processes it and redirects to some result controller. And if an intermediate controller is not used, the search strings will not be available in the URL anymore. I want to have my query string in the URL for various reasons.

Is it ok if I use the GET method in laravel forms?

```
{{ Form::open('search', 'GET') }}
```

Or are there any specific benefits of using the POST method?

Here is an example application built on laravel:

http://www.bootsnipp.com

The search page does not append any query strings. I don't the search to be like this.

Comment: This question has nothing do with laravel. Google the difference between get and post form. There are specific cases as when to use which. They are not replaceable with each other (in most cases).

Comment: I know the difference between POST and GET. In a regular/core PHP project, I'd use GET for the above example. But in laravel/codeigniter, all tutorials show us using POST even for the example above(searching). So am asking if there is any reason/benefit they use it that way.

Comment: Framework is no different than php. It just gives some head start. What is true for php, is true for frameworks.

Comment: Laravel is a lot different than COdeigniter. Also, you mention example: they're just that, sample codes, you can't expect to find a snippet for everything you want to do. Once you know the rules, you can play by yourself

Answer (score 1):

Based on experience for searching always use GET. and for hidden data use post for example Login.

Even google us using get method for searching.

Answer (score 1):

[Laravel provides the options for controllers to be RESTful](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers). By turning RESTful on, your controller can responds to RESTful commands such as `POST`, `GET`, `DELETE` and `PUT`

Using the `Form::open()` method, you can pick any of the four options. If you decide to use `GET` - then your `get_method()` will be called. If you decide to use `POST` - then your `post_method` will be called.

Following general RESTful commands, you would use `POST` to create a record. As you are retrieving a record, `GET` is the appropriate choice.